# Optional fields and constraints in Protocol Buffers (protobuf) v3.0.0-alpha-2

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am currently playing around with v3.0.0-alpha-2 of Google [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf).

As far as I understand v3 removes the `required` keyword, the `extensions`
keyword and default values for fields to simplify the proto language.

What I **do not** understand is the meaning of the `optional` keyword in proto3.

*Example:*

```
syntax = "proto3";

package fw.example;

message ExampleMessage {
  optional string optional_string = 1;
  string normal_string = 2;
}
```

*Question:* What is the difference between `optional_string` and `normal_string`
besides the name and the tag?

I've already read the following resources (they seem to be the only publicly
available yet for v3 of protobuf):

- [Protocol Buffers v3.0.0-alpha-2 Release Notes](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha-2)
- [proto3 Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3)

But they do not even mention the `optional` keyword.

- Is `optional` obsolete in proto3, since a field is always optional?
- How can one enforce required fields with proto3 if `required` is gone?

It seems that in proto3 one cannot longer distinguish between unset fields and
fields set by a client to the (implicit) default value.

Is the best practice to wrap each proto3 message in a language-specific class?
I am using C++ and I need to ensure that specific fields are set. It seems that
validation has to be done manually in language-specific source code now, in
contrast to proto2.

Can someone enlighten me, what's the best approach to apply constraints on a
proto3 message but allow scheme evolution? At the moment I think that a new API
has to be written around the proto3 messages, so that a client does not deal
directly with the proto3 generated code, but with the custom API code. Is that
correct?

Maybe someone can show me a concrete example to discuss about.

I am pretty confused, since the following is stated in the release notes of v3:

> We recommend that new Protocol Buffers users use proto3. However, we do not
>   generally recommend that existing users migrate from proto2 from proto3 due to
>   API incompatibility, and we will continue to support proto2 for a long time.

If proto3 is the way-to-go, why are things complicated? It seems to me that I do need to write a lot more code than with proto2 now.

Comment: If your code is for production use I think I'd stick to version 2 until all the bugs and documentation errors have been ironed out

Comment: @RichardHodges but the json serialization of proto3 is Oooh-So-sweet!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My reasoning is as follows:

Since `required` is obsolete, then everything is `optional`. Thus there is no reason for explicit keyword.

The following paragraph from [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other) indicates how values are initialized if not set:

> Note that for scalar message fields, once a message is parsed there's
>   no way of telling whether a field was explicitly set to the default
>   value (for example whether a boolean was set to false) or just not set
>   at all: you should bear this in mind when defining your message types.

So `optional` really means "if you didn't set it explicitly, we'll set it to default value for you!"

Note that this allows them to do some nice optimization (not include the value on the wire if it's set to default):

> For example, don't have a boolean that switches on some behaviour when
>   set to false if you don't want that behaviour to also happen by
>   default. Also note that if a scalar message field is set to its
>   default, the value will not be serialized on the wire.

Comment: It seems like a big step backwards to lose the "has_XXX" methods on the generated code. Despite the advice above, it's not practical to try to organize a service interface so that this works. I find myself thinking about having embedded messages (which support "has"), or awkward interactions where the client can make a request for all defaults, and then "cherry-pick" overrides.

Comment: After 3.12 (experimental) and 3.15 (official) the `optional` keyword has special [meaning](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md) again. And it's there to support tracking field presence.

Answer (score 6):

The proto3 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other) (section "Using proto2 Message Types") says that you can import proto2 .proto files with the 'import' keyword, and vice versa. That means the v2 and v3 .proto syntaxes are compatible, and that implies that optional and required are still supported.

I say give it a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The final version of proto3 does not have the `optional` keyword. In proto3, [all fields are optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622015/how-to-define-an-optional-field-in-protobuf-3).

Comment: From 3.12 (experimental) and 3.15 (official) the `optional` keyword is [added back](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md) again.

Answer (score 1):

From 3.12 (experimental) and 3.15 (official) the `optional` keyword has special [meaning](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md) again. The feature is implemented on top of `oneof` and it's there to support tracking field presence.

E.g., previously `has_xxx()` (in C++) was only generated for fields of message types. Now they are also generated for `oneof` and `optional` fields.

So, if you declare `optional int field = 1;` in your message proto, then you will be able to distinguish between the field being explicitly set to default value 0 and not being set at all, by using `has_field()` generated method.