# How to Pass enum In Grpc Request

Tags: c#, grpc

I want to define such a router or Map for my gRPC Server using Enum or similar method

I've a simple Service which named ServerHubService and a Hubs folder which have some classes in it which will be handle every request will be passed by client to my gRPC server

Here is ScreenShot of my Project
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXoT3.jpg)
Now as can be seen in the photo
The contents of the file are also the image below
[HubMap.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8m9.jpg)

as you can see i want to define a switch case statment to run diffrent classes

Here is my ServiceHubService gRPC class
[ServerHubService.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsyfg.jpg)

and finally this my client side call [grpc-client.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWbe9.jpg)

visual studio 2019 ver 16.10

Here is my ServerHub.proto file :

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "NetPlus.Server.Core";

package server;


service ServereHub  {

rpc ActionManager (ActionRequest) returns (ActionResult);

}

message ActionRequest {
    string ActionType = 1;
}

message ActionResult {
    string ActionResultType = 1;
}
```

my ServerHubService.cs :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NetPlus.Server.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NetPlus.Server.Core.Hubs;
namespace NetPlus.Server.Core
{
    public class ServerHubService : ServereHub.ServereHubBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ServerHubService> _logger;

       public ServerHubService(ILogger<ServerHubService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task<ActionResult> ActionManager(ActionRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            HubMap map = new HubMap();
            HubMap.HubSelector selector;

         
            return Task.FromResult(new ActionResult
            {
                ActionResultType = map.HubProccessor(selector)
            }) ;
        }
    }
    
}
```

and Hubmap.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetPlus.Server.Core.Hubs
{
    public class HubMap
    {
        Switcher switcher = new Switcher();

        public string HubNameResult { get; set; }
        public   enum HubSelector
        {
            SwitchServer_Off  = 1

        }
       
        public  string HubProccessor(HubSelector hName) =>
          
        
            hName switch
            {
                HubSelector.SwitchServer_Off => switcher.PutOffline(),
               
                _=> "Error Proccesing  Hub"
            };
        
        
    }

}
```

Problem 2 : Whats this error
[image]

Question 2:

How to Detect Defined enums in proto file and proccess in  HubMap.cs

Comment: The main issue here appears to be simply that you aren't using `async`; that should be `public async Task<string> CustomMethodAsync(...)` or `public async ValueTask<string> CustomMethodAsync(...)`, no?

Comment: no i get error ' can not convert from HubMap.HubSelector to string

Comment: you're also showing some broken code in `ActionManager` that is due to "definite assignment" (of `selector`); it would be really good if you could ask a *specific* question, making it clear what problem you're asking about; in particular, saying what compiler error you're asking about (the red squigglies)

Comment: "no i get error ' can not convert from HubMap.HubSelector to string" - and we would have guessed that how, exactly? that's exactly why I'm saying to be explicit; now; we can't see your `ActionRequest` type, so ... help us out here; is `ActionRequest.ActionType` defined as `string`? and: should it be?

Comment: Additionally, showing all the code as text within the question, rather than as screenshots, would help...

Comment: simply i want to pass enum element  as grpc request

Comment: @SecGenUnity "simply i want to pass enum element as grpc request" - that works perfectly fine, assuming the field is *defined* as that enum in the .proto; we also can't see your .proto (note: you can't pass *just* an enum, but you can pass a message type that *has* just an enum)

Comment: As a side note: I should add that if both your client and server are C#, you can bypass the .proto stage entirely - via protobuf-net.Grpc, which uses a code-first approach: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass an enum over gRPC: *define* the enum in gRPC terms:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "NetPlus.Server.Core";

package server;

enum ActionType
{   // whatever contents...
    Foo = 0;
    Bar = 1;
    Blap = 2;
}
enum ActionResultType
{
    // ... etc
}
service ServereHub  {
   rpc ActionManager (ActionRequest) returns (ActionResult);
}

message ActionRequest {
    ActionType Action = 1;
}

message ActionResult {
    ActionResultType Result = 1;
}
```

And use the *generated* enums. If you *don't* want to do that and want to use `string` instead: then all the conversions back and fore are *up to you*; `ToString()` and `Enum.Parse` are your friends.

Comment: do i need to use meesage keyword before enum?

Comment: @SecGenUnity no; enums *can* be nested inside a `message` if you so choose and if that makes sense, but they do not need to be - they can be top-level like shown. It could also make sense to define `ActionType` inside `ActionRequest` and `ActionResultType` inside `ActionResult` - **if** they aren't used anywhere else

Comment: What do you do if the enum has an OriginalName? In my case, the C# enum is Upper Camel Cased and the original name is all capitals for the most part. I realize I could hack it with some janky string manipulation, but would like to understand what the heck gRPC _expects_ me to do?

Comment: @JohnZabroski gRPC (by default) uses the binary protobuf encoding, which doesn't care about names - names are not transmitted

Comment: Some of the enums are mapped on the message as strings, not enum values - others are straightforward and mapped on the message as an enum as well. This is my first gRPC project, as a client API user. I'm sure I will figure this out in a few days time, but I could not find straightforward explanations on enums and what purpose OriginalName serves. e.g., do I need to call a special reflection helper to put the OriginalName value in the string field in the message? Trying to Google/Bing/Brave this has been kind of painful.

Comment: @JohnZabroski vanilla protobuf doesn't have an OriginalName AFAIK; what language/toolset are you using here? And again, usually the binary form: doesn't use names. If you're doing a string convert, that's up to you...

Comment: I had a beginner misunderstanding. OriginalName is just for language-specific customizations to follow naming conventions of that ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look at the google protobuf guidelines.

[Naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention#enum_names)

[Designpatterns](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#enum_default_value)

The generated Enums will be PascalCase (FOO_BAR => FooBar)

Comment: So the convention is that 0 in an enum should denote "unspecified"? Is that like a nullable value type in C#? It looks like as of proto version 3.15, the "optional" keyword is available and should be used instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566052/1040437

Comment: @JohnZabroski i think it's more about versioning than making it nullable, if you have a new version of the service (v2) with a new enum variable and want to call it from an old client the value will be unspecified by default