# Does protobuf message (c++) class provide method like size() and empty()?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

For example, we define a `Person` message.

```
message Person {
   int32 age = 1;
   string name = 2;
};
```

I want to use this message in the following way:

```
Person p;
assert(p.empty());
p.set_age(10);
assert(p.size() == 1);  // True
p.Clear()
assert(p.empty()) // True
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What should "size" return exactly?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your desire to have a `empty()` function you can use the `has()` function for optional fields in proto3. This has been added as of [version 3.15](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0). An example has given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566052/10397400).

Comment: Ok, So the only way is to iterate all the fields names and check that all `has_xyz` method returns false.

Comment: Likely yes, there might be a short cut for messages nested in other messages. The nested message have a has_ function in the parent I from the top of my head I would say return true if at least one variable is set

Comment: Thanks. In my case the message is not a field in another message.  Maybe I can use DebugString().empty() instead.