# Google Protobuf handle null values

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

somebody explain me how can handle null values in google protobuf .
i have structure like this :

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
message Person {
  google.protobuf.DoubleValue age = 4;
}
```

and java code :

```
DoubleValue myAge = null;
Person build = Person.newBuilder()
                .setAge(myAge)  // <- NPE
                .build();
```

this code result null pointer exception on `.setAge(myAge)` line.
so what is use case of protobuf DoubleValue ? I thought it was used to manage null values . but still receive NullPointerException .

Do you use code like this for handle this problem ?

```
DoubleValue a = null;
Person.Builder builder = Person.newBuilder();
if (a != null) {
    builder.setAge(a);
}

Person build = builder.build();
```

**UPDATE:**
this is part of code generated by protoc command :

```
/**
* <code>.google.protobuf.DoubleValue age = 9;</code>
*/
public Builder setAge(com.google.protobuf.DoubleValue value) {
if (ageBuilder_ == null) {
    if (value == null) {        //<-- Additional statement
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    age_ = value;
    onChanged();
} else {
    ageBuilder_.setMessage(value);
}
```

Why set additional `if` statement in generated code ?
I think this is a bug for google protocol buffer.
finally i wrote this code:

```
DoubleValue.Builder builder = DoubleValue.newBuilder();
DoubleValue myAge = null;
Person build = Person.newBuilder()
                .setAge(myAge != null ? myAge : builder )
                .build();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `optional` in your proto schema?

Comment: I use proto3 , by default all fields is optional . (not need)

Comment: If that's the case, the tutorial needs updated https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Comment: Yes, the code you wrote there is how to correctly handle this with Protos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoubleValue` is meant to handle **missing** values, not necessarily `null`. Protobuf libraries are intended to never involve nulls - for example, it never returns `null`, even for missing fields. Also, as you've found out, setters don't accept null. For example, to clear a field you'd use `clearField` instead of `setField(null)`.

One of the big differences between proto2 and proto3 is that ([initially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566052/340862))  "hazzers" for primitive fields (e.g. `hasField`) were removed. That is, if you have a `double my_field`, there is no way to tell if it was never set, or set explicitly to zero. `getMyField()` would return 0 in both cases.

Note that messages still have hazzers, so if you want that functionality, you could wrap your primitive field in a message. Which is exactly what [`DoubleValue` is](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/e60ec85b9f6ec4a3b45a25848922bd3571b59de8/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto#L56). So if you have a field `DoubleValue age = 1`, you could use `hasAge()` to determine if it's set. In newer protobuf version, you could do the same with `optional double age = 1`.

Note that all of this has no relation with `null` in the Java generated code. There really is no way a setter would accept a null value.

TL;DR: Your first suggestion is good and very common:

```
DoubleValue a = null;
Person.Builder builder = Person.newBuilder();
if (a != null) {
    builder.setAge(a);
}
Person build = builder.build();
```

If instead of null you have an `Optional`, you could use a similar variant:

```
OptionalDouble a = OptionalDouble.empty();
Person.Builder builder = Person.newBuilder();
a.ifPresent(value-> builder.getAgeBuilder().setValue(value));

Person build = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

For dart you can set it as:

> DoubleValue(value: null)