# Consistent Cross Platform Proto3 Serialization / Deserialization

Tags: node.js, go, grpc, proto

I have a golang based GRPC service defined with **proto3**

```
syntax = "proto3";
```

For a simple Response of a single bool filed if the value is `false` the whole message is serialized just as an empty (zero length) data payload. (as my suspect, treating `false` as a default one)

Same time a node's GRPC client built from the very same `.proto` definition interprets the value as an `undefined`. (while `true` one is pretty consistent)

Debugging the way [server builds the response](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/30d54d398f70876f81aec64875e4540d9a40b1b8/server.go#L1073)

```
data, err := encode(s.getCodec(stream.ContentSubtype()), msg)
```

I've noticed, `stream.ContentSubtype()` returns an empty string so that within `s.getCodec` it is falls back to `encoding/proto.Name` which is just `proto`. And it leads further encoding something [over here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/wire.go#L37)

```
func marshalAppend(buf []byte, m Message, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    if m == nil {
        return nil, ErrNil
    }
    mi := MessageV2(m)
    nbuf, err := protoV2.MarshalOptions{
        Deterministic: deterministic,
        AllowPartial:  true,
    }.MarshalAppend(buf, mi)
```

Which looks like really `protoV2` implementation.

So I don't know what is really the right question here

- Should `stream.ContentSubtype()` be somehow controlled on a communication level and who's to be responsible for this (Client/Server)
- Should any additional control steps/actions be followed while generating client/server source codes from the `.proto` definition. Doesn't `.proto` it self generalize the meta enough to output consistent sources?
- Should/Cloud `proto3` be really encoded successfully with `protoV2` implementation?
- What else could cause such inconsistent values treatment?

Comment: What you are seeing in go appears to [comply with the spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default) "For bools, the default value is false.". Note that [`optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566052/11810946) is now supported in proto3 (and if specified would change things a bit).

Comment: @Brits, got it thanks. Still what is the way to guarantee the encoded stuff to be treated on a client side exactly the same way it was encoded?

Comment: This is most likely just a deserialization setting on the client. What protobuf implementation are you using on the client?

Comment: @murgatroid99 https://www.npmjs.com/package/protoc-gen-ts, and I will take a look on some alternatives now

Comment: Oh, I am not familiar with that one. You may have some luck filing an issue on that library's GitHub project.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/thesayyn/protoc-gen-ts/issues/107) in the `proto-gen-ts` repo discusses the problem.

Comment: @murgatroid99 maybe you can share some other useful implementations as an alternative to play with?

Comment: The `@grpc/proto-loader` and `grpc-tools` libraries are officially maintained by the gRPC maintainers. Note that the code generated by `grpc-tools` also depends on the `google-protobuf` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was nothing with misconfiguration but a matter of specific implementation.

Six days ago it was fixed within [porto-gen-ts v0.8.5](https://github.com/thesayyn/protoc-gen-ts/pull/146)

Thanks @Brits for a lookup