# google.protobuf.doublevalue is not convert to option[double]

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I write proto like this

```
message I {
    google.protobuf.DoubleValue supplierCommissionAmount = 1;

}
```

It convert to below code

```
final case class I(
    variable: _root_.scala.Double = 0.0,
    
)
```

but I expect to be Option[Double]

```
final case class I(
    variable : _root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Double] = _root_.scala.None,

    
)
```

How to solve it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622015/how-to-define-an-optional-field-in-protobuf-3

Comment: Does adding `optional` solve your question?

Comment: Optional  and oneof can not solve

Comment: Looks like you are out of luck: "In proto2, optional fields are represented as Option[]. In proto3, optional primitives are not wrapped in Option[], but messages are."
https://scalapb.github.io/docs/getting-started/

Comment: @PanidaYimsanga *"Optional and oneof can not solve"* Please see https://github.com/DmytroMitin/protobufdemo I [added](https://github.com/DmytroMitin/protobufdemo/blob/main/src/main/protobuf/myproto.proto#L11) `optional double d = 6` and I [can see](https://github.com/DmytroMitin/protobufdemo/blob/main/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main/scalapb/com/example/myproto/MyClass.scala#L15) `d: _root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Double] = _root_.scala.None`. What am I doing wrong to reproduce?

Comment: @Dima ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @PanidaYimsanga Are we using different versions?

Comment: @PanidaYimsanga Also it's `Option` with `google.protobuf.DoubleValue` instead of `double` https://github.com/DmytroMitin/protobufdemo/commit/344834ff22baaf09364f21488fff7f29c95f3fcb